# Why does a query with an IN (subquery) take longer than a query with IN (discrete list)

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

This has always bugged me, why does this query

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `TABLE` 
WHERE `value` IN 
  (SELECT 
    val 
  FROM
    OTHER_TABLE 
  WHERE `date` < '2014-01-01')
```

run orders of magnitude slower than sequentially running both this query

```
SELECT 
  `val` 
FROM
  OTHER_TABLE 
WHERE `date` < '2014-01-01' 

Result:
+----+
| val |
+-----+
| v1  |
| v2  |
| v3  |
| v7  |
| v12 |
+-----+
```

and this query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `TABLE` 
WHERE `value` IN ('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v7', 'v12')
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: (emphasis added by me)

> Subquery optimization for `IN` is not as effective as for the `=` operator
>   or for the `IN(value_list)` operator.
>
> A typical case for poor `IN` subquery performance is when the subquery
>   returns a small number of rows but the outer query returns a large
>   number of rows to be compared to the subquery result.
>
> The problem is that, for a statement that uses an `IN` subquery, the
>   optimizer rewrites it as a correlated subquery. Consider the following
>   statement that uses an uncorrelated subquery:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE t1.a IN (SELECT b FROM t2);`
>
> The optimizer rewrites the statement to a correlated subquery:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.b = t1.a);`
>
> **If the inner and outer queries return M and N rows, respectively, the
>   execution time becomes on the order of `O(M×N)`, rather than `O(M+N)` as
>   it would be for an uncorrelated subquery.**
>
> An implication is that an `IN` subquery can be much slower than a query
>   written using an `IN(value_list)` operator that lists the same values
>   that the subquery would return.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html

Hopes this helps anyone else who might have been curious

Comment: Is this true of all versions?

Comment: @Strawberry good question, I found that answer (while looking for something else) on google, and the 5.0 doc happened to show up. I have verified that *that portion* of the article is identical to the 5.7 doc, and I have updated the link accordingly

Comment: @Strawberry: that's been true for a *long* time; I can't say it's for all versions. (Back in MySQL 3.23, we couldn't even use a subquery.) This *well documented* behavior and *well tested* performance differences is why some of us continually and strongly advocate alternatives to the ubiquitous `IN/NOT IN (subquery)` form.  It's never a problem for small sets, where we never notice the performance difference. It's when we scale up to a real volume of data, that the performance difference is *significant*.